# Who was the first theorist to define a list of psychological defense mechanisms?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, history-of-psychology, freud

The obvious answer is Sigmund Freud, but was there a theorist before him who created a list of specific defense mechanisms? A defense mechanism can be defined as a method by which the mind protects itself from thoughts, feelings, impulses, and/or stimuli which would be damaging to its overall health.

Comment: I think you gave yourself the textbook answer. To assign this novelty to someone before him would take considerable [re]interpretation because Freud [came up](https://books.google.com/books?id=zbWn6P7r2WwC&pg=PA244) with the notion of psychological defence in the first place.